# Where should I define the column default logic to default the order of contacts on a SQL Server database, with a C# rest API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

We have a system where there is a many to many relationship between a contact and a form. A contact can have many forms and the form has many contacts it has been determined that the order of those contacts on a form is important. So we have added to the relationship table between `Form` and `Contacts` (`FormContacts`) a sort order column. This column should default to `max(SortOrder) + 1 where FormID = @FormID`.

Technology being used:

- SQL Server database
- C# REST API, EF, with defined model, DTO, and controllers

Where would you define this logic and how would you implement it?

Comment: What does the structure of FormContacts currently look like?

Comment: FormContactID, FormID, ContactID, (A bunch of other attributes that are unique to the relationship), SortOrder

Comment: @SkiGeek when you say "where would you define this logic", what do you mean?

Comment: @CodingYoshi - As in, I could define it on the database as either a Stored Procedure or a Trigger, or I could define it on the C# code either on the Model or in the Controller.

Comment: If you define it in your C# app, you'll have to make two database calls for each record, one to get the MAX(SortOrder) for the FormID, then another call to insert all the compiled data. You could do this with a trigger, but doing everything in a single stored proc will probably be the most efficient solution.

Comment: @digital.aaron - very good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a stored proc to do the inserting, then use the MAX(SortOrder)+1 in a subquery, maybe like this:

```
CREATE PROC FormContactsInserter
(
    @FormID INT,
    @ContactID INT,
    @UniqueDataPoint VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
INSERT INTO FormContacts
(FormID, ContactID, UniqueDataPoint, SortOrder)
VALUES
(@FormID, @ContactID, @UniqueDataPoint, (SELECT MAX(SortOrder)+1 FROM FormContacts WHERE FormID = @FormID))
```

Comment: Thanks @digital.aaron, this would work but currently our database doesn't have any stored procedures, it doesn't mean I couldn't add one but I am looking for additional solution.  But this may be necessary as part of our data migration.